# How to upload multiple images with one value in Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I'm trying to upload multiple images with one single field, in a Django application.

How to do this?

The following files are involved:

`upload.html`:

```
<form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <input type="text" name="image_id" placeholder="Image Id">
    <input type="file" name="file" multiple>
    <button type="submit"> Upload </button>
</form>
```

Here, the single field `image_id` is meant to hold `5` images.

`views.py`:

```
def multi_image(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        img_id = request.POST.get('image_id')
        file = request.FILES.getlist('file')
        data_save = Res(image_id = img_id )
        data_save.save()
        filter_data = Res.objects.filter(image_id= img_id)
        if len(filter_data) > 0:
            for i in file:
                print(i)
                Res.objects.create(image= i)

    return render(request, 'upload.html', {})
```

`models.py`:

```
class Res(models.Model):
    image_id= models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='images', blank=True, null=True)
```

`forms.py`:

```
class FileForm(forms.Form):
    class Meta:
        model = Res
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Here in your forms you should be using `ModelForm`  instead of `Form`

Comment: I tried that one also but result is same

Comment: Take a look [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/file-uploads/#uploading-multiple-files)